# Templated unique pointer

Tags: c++, oop, templates, smart-pointers

I'm quite new to C++.

I have a class called `Main_Alg` which runs the (generic) main algorithm. I have different classes with the base class `Calc_Type` and two derived classes say class `A` and class `B`.

When `Main_Alg` is created `run` will run the generic algorithm, with the method solve of either `A` or `B` (which is pure virtual in `Calc_Type`). Which one is executed is specified by the user.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I thought of a template class `Main_alg`:

```cpp
if (parms == "A"){
    std::unique_ptr<Main_Alg<A>> main_alg(new Main_alg<A>);
    main_alg -> run;
}
else ... // for B or whatever
```

in run:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<T> method;
method -> solve;
method -> getsmthg; //method only implemented for base class Calc_type `
```

Would this be over-complicating things? Is this good practice? Also any suggestion for reading is appreciated

Comment: Regarding your example, `Main_Alg` is the template, `Main_Alg<A>` is the class. You have to use the class as the template argument for `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Explanation of the problem is still to foggy.

Comment: I basically want to have a general class (Main_Alg) which uses the method solve (which is a member function of class A and class B). Depending on the template either A or B is created and the solve of either A or B is executed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<Main_Alg> main_alg(new Main_alg<A>;
> ```

This is not possible. `Main_alg` can be either a class template, or a class. It cannot be both. The fist template argument of `std::unique_ptr` is a template type argument; not a template template argument.

I think a following function template might be appropriate:

```
template<class T>
void run()
{
    Main_Alg<T> m;
    m.run();
}
```

and call:

```
if (parms == "A"){
    run<A>();
else
    run<B>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to C++ do not write own templates. They are cool, but quite hard to master especially when you beginning to code in C++.

You have wrote something about pure virtual class. If you have it then you do not need templates.

```cpp
class Calc_Type {
    virtual ~Calc_Type() {}
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class A : public Calc_Type {
public:
    void run() override {
        stuff_to_do();
    }
};

class B : public Calc_Type {
public:
    void run() override {
        other_stuff_to_do();
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Calc_Type> createJob(const std::string& name)
{
    if (name = "A") {
        return std::make_unique<A>();
    } else if (name = "B") {
        return std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    return std::make_unique<NoJob>();
}

// somewhere in the code:
auto job = createJob(userInput);
...
job->run();
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you :)